# Lock a button while an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

On click of a button, I am saving the record to the database. I don't want to refresh the page, it must be handled through AJAX.

I have the code for AJAX, I just want to know how to enable/disable the Submit button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
document.getElementById('submitId').disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
```

then

```
var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
submit.disabled = true;
```

Comment: You're argument is sound. I removed my Answer. Cheers.